# SharpDevelop vs Visual Studio alt-ins code completion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharpdevelop

SharpDevelop has a really cool feature for [code completion](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/siegfried_pammer/archive/2010/04/09/what-happened-to-alt-ins-in-sharpdevelop-4-0.aspx) in special cases.  In some cases, very little modification is needed for the code completed when it spits out code for a constructor or overridden `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`, and the `Equals()` methods. It allows you to select properties from your class to be included, null checks in constructors, etc.

Does Visual Studio have anything like this (does Resharper do this)?  Since my office is straight Microsoft, I generally have to develop in VS (plus I like VS's text alignment better).

Answer (score 1):

For a few things SharpDevelop does you can use [Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx). There is a rather long list of snippets already included, like `ctor`, `switch` blocks, `try...catch` blocks, etc.

You can also add your own [placeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx) for example. It doesn't include variable / property names, but a lot of other stuff though.

For overrides it adds a default template, but that one isn't that complete as SharpDevelops one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything should be possible with VS, for example:

1. Use: Alt + Shift + F10 then press enter
2. The same as 1
3. Just type override and you get a window with all options
4. ...
5. ...
6. Press Ctrl + R + E
7. just write `ctor` and press Tab